# zsh (or maybe oh-my-zsh) history gets confused with multi-line commands

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

if I use the up arrow in a zsh session, as you'd expect I get previous commands, from newest to oldest. Now (whether it's zsh or oh-my-zsh doing this I don't know), but if I type the start of a line and hit the up arrow I get the lines from my history that start with whatever I've typed. All good so far.

The problem occurs if I type in a multi line command, eg:

```
for i in foo bar
echo $i
```

then if I later hit the up arrow, once it gets to the multi line command it will then only display results starting with `for`. So if my history is like:

```
touch foo
rm foo
for i in foo bar
echo $i
ls
```

and I hit the up arrow I get the `ls` command then the multi-line `for` command, and from then on I only see only `for` commands that are in my history, rather than the `rm` or `touch` commands.

Is there any way to be able to search chronologically, without getting stuck whenever the history gets to a multi-line command?

Comment: This works as expected with `zsh -f` (version 5.0.5). Check especially the `bindkey` commands in your personal `.zshrc` files, including those sourced by d'oh-my-zsh.

Comment: What is the output of `bindkey | grep -e '\^\[.A'`?

Comment: `"^[OA" up-line-or-history` and `"^[[A" up-line-or-search`

Comment: for anyone with a similar question the keybindings in D'oh-my-zsh are in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh`

Comment: @Adaephon When I run ```bindkey | grep -e '\^\[.A'``` I get two lines returned, ```"^[OA" up-line-or-beginning-search``` and ```"^[[A" up-line-or-history```. What should I do to remedy the same as OP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour described is due to the use of `up-line-or-search`, which will move up through the line of a command and on the first line of a command it will search in the history for lines beginning with the first word.

**Explanation for your issue:** 
Starting from an empty line any line in the history will match. As long as only single-line commands are found there is no difference in behaviour to `up-history` or `up-line-or-history`. But when reaching a multi-line command it is no longer searching but going through the lines. When the top line is reached it starts a new search, but now it is looking for the first word in this line instead of continuing the old search for any line.

By default *Up* is mapped to `up-line-or-history`, which goes backward through the history entries and in case of multi-line commands through each line. `up-history` would also go through the history but treat multi-line commands just like single-line ones. Both would provide the expected behaviour.

I'd suggest searching your zsh and Oh-my-ZSH configuration for where `up-line-or-search` is bound and replace it with `up-line-or-history` or delete the binding as `up-line-or-history` is the default anyway.

Also, depending on the terminal used, the key sequenze for *Up* is either `^[OA` or `^[[A`. To get consisten behaviour from your shell, both should be set to the same commands.